# Show the same array value twice in a tabe PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

This is maybe an obvious question but I can not resolve it so I prefer to ask it.

I have an array ($fechas[]) with consecutive dates, from startdate to enddate.

I want to show each value twice in this table.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $sesion ; $i++) 
{ 
 $d = date( "d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[$i]) );
 echo "<tr><td>FECHA: ".$d."</td></tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

$sesion is always multiple of 2.

So if $sesion is 4 and $fechas has two dates, the table has to show:

```
FECHA: echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[0])))
FECHA: echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[0])))
FECHA: echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[1])))
FECHA: echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[1])))
```

$fechas is something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 2014-02-03 [1] => 2014-02-04 )
```

I want to show each cell of $fechas[] each two iterations of the loop.

Comment: Not clear, show content of your array `$fechas[]`

Comment: Thanks, added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you refer to this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $sesion ; $i++) { ?>
<tr><td>FECHA: <? echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[floor($i/2)]))) ?></td></tr>
<? } ?>
```

floor($i/2) keeps same value on each two consecutive loops

Comment: As simple as this seems, I can't imagine that there is a better answer judging by my interpretation of the author's question.

Comment: Haha unfortunately this is not a solution. That "for" comes with more rows, I need the same date each two iterations.

Comment: well, I am guessing. you say `So if $sesion is 4 and $fechas has two dates, the table has to show: ...four rows...` two rows twice are four rows, do you have other related arrays that index diferent? can you show them? and how are they related?

Comment: I think it could be a solution. I am going to try that and I wrote you back. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i=0; $i < $sesion ; $i++) { ?>
<? $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechas[$i]));?>
<tr><td>FECHA: <? echo $date ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>FECHA: <? echo $date ?></td></tr>
<? } ?>
```